# Is ExecStop run when issuing systemctl restart myUnit?

Tags: linux, systemd

Is the [ExecStop](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=) directive in a unit file called when running `systemctl restart ...` or only when doing a literal `systemctl stop ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is searching for this later, this is now explained explicitly in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> Service restart requests are implemented as stop operations followed
>   by start operations. This means that ExecStop= and ExecStopPost= are
>   executed during a service restart operation.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is not specified in the `systemd` docs where `systemctl restart` is documented, or where `ExecStop=` is documented.  I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7126) with `systemd` to clarify the behavior upstream.